# rewrite rule for _escape_fragment_

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, seo

i want to write a rewrite rule for

http://www.site.com/noticia/?_escaped_fragment_=noticia=/279/beto-cuevas3er-sencillo-dej-de-pensar

to:

http://www.site.com/noticia/#!noticia=/279/beto-cuevas3er-sencillo-dej-de-pensar

i've tried this but is far from what i need right?

```
# Enable Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine on

#Create friendly URL
RewriteRule ^index.php?_escaped_fragment=something=yes$ 
index.php/#!something=yes [L]
```

Comment: AFAIK You can't rewrite with # in them. it's client side only.

Comment: This does not seem to be a good way to implement #!. Your trying to make the ugly version return exactly the same content as the friendly version. Which defeats the whole point of the exercise that the ugly one will return the plain text of the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=([^=]+)=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /%1/#!%1=%2? [L,R,NE]
```

Comment: actually this is redirecting me to domain.com/#!noticia=
i was expecting domain.com/noticia/#!noticia=......

Comment: excelent!! but what about adding another folder before? its ok if i do
RewriteRule ^$ /test/%1/#!%1=%2? [L,R,NE]   It's a fixed folder, always the same

Comment: k its working! thanks sr!!

Comment: This also defeats the point but gets round the # being stripped. When Google sees the ugly version redirect to the friendly version they will know it is of no use to them. The whole problem is that Google will not process pages using #s to create dynamic content. You will put them in a loop trying to find your plain content.